# What is the name of the default eBook file icon in Xubuntu 15.10?

Tags: xubuntu, icons

The default eBook file (`.epub`) icon in Xubuntu 15.10 looks like this:

[image: default eBook file icon]

I have cropped this icon from a screenshot to be able to paste it here.

What is the name of this icon file and how could I find it out myself? `grep 'epub' /etc/mime.types` shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/*/application-epub+zip.png`:

[image]

How did I find it?

1. Look up mimetype of an epub file, which turned out to be `application/epub+zip`.
2. Look up the default Xubuntu icon theme, which is `elementary-xfce` provided by the [`xubuntu-icon-theme`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/xubuntu-icon-theme) package
3. Look in the `mimes` directory of that icon theme. There are `application-epub+zip.png` files available for sizes 16, 22, 24, 32, 48 and 64.